# PostgreSQL server fails to start on ArchLinux: FATAL: could not create lockfile »/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock«

Tags: postgresql, archlinux

I am quite new in Arch and a total beginner in PostgreSQL, so this may be a very basic question.

I installed postgresql 11.5-4 from extra and pgadmin 4 from AUR, both seem to be running well.
I created a test DB with the following command:

```
initdb -D /home/lg/test-db
```

I got the answer:

```
You can start the db-server using:
pg_ctl -D /home/lg/test-db -l logdatei start
```

I tried that and got:

```
pg_ctl -D /home/lg/test-db -l logdatei start
waiting for serer to start.... stopped 
pg_ctl: could not start the server
check the log.
```

The log only says that the lockfile  »/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock« could not be created, because the folder could not be found. Under /run is no folder called "postgresql". I suppose postgresql can not create this folder, because it does not have the permission. Several posts online posts suggest to change the user/owner of the db to sudo, however. Postgresql prevents this, however. When I try any command as sudo, postgresql tells me that this command can't be run as root. There must be some very basic error in my thinking here, but I have not worked it out for 3 hours.

Comment: You seem to have another instance running from another data directory (look for `postmaster.pid` somewhere else on your server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to remove `/run/postgresql` from `unix_socket_directories` in `postgresql.conf` before starting the server.

Comment: Thank you. I tried two ways, setting unix_socket_directories to a folder in /home/lg and leaving it blank. The error remains the same. The Logfile says:

+2019-11-26 06:20:47.659 CET [1917] LOG: expect connections at IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
+2019-11-26 06:20:47.659 CET [1917] LOG: expect connections at IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
+2019-11-26 06:20:47.662 CET [1917] FATAL: could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": File or directory not found
+2019-11-26 06:20:47.662 CET [1917] LOG: Database system is shut down

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to remove the comment (`#`) in front of the line.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you very much. Just for information: I set unix_socket_directories = '/home/lg/test-db' which is the directory of the db itself. I am not sure, if this is wise. The file postmaster.pid, which was missing before, did appear after the db-server started. It is now in the folder /home/lg/test-db.

Comment: The default (and canonical) location is `/tmp`. You can set it to `''` if you don't need Unix socket connections.

Comment: This also solved the problem for me, but why does this work? The documentation for unix_sockets_directories states: "An empty value specifies not listening on any Unix-domain sockets, in which case only TCP/IP sockets can be used to connect to the server." For me this does not mean a non-empty value prevents TCP/IP socket connections.

Comment: @Martin This is nor about connecting, it is about starting PostgreSQL. The server refuses to start if it cannot create the socket file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You have /var/run symlinked to /run and run is on tmpfs. You should add something like `d /run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -` into /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf